# Clojure how to get access to one field from two threads?

Tags: multithreading, loops, clojure

Can't understand multithreading in clojure. Can't find examples of REAL multithreading. Most samples with atoms, refs, vars are singlethreaded. So, I have a quest. Two threads gaining access to one field, each thread can change it. I use atom for this purpose, so the Code is:

```
   (do
     (def field (atom "v0"))

     (defn f1 []
       (dotimes [i 100000]
         (if (= i 9999)
           (reset! field "v1"))))

     (defn f2 []
       (dotimes [i 100000]
         (if (= i 777)
           (reset! field "v2"))))

   (do
     (deref (future (Thread/sleep 10) (f1))
            0 f2)
     (prn @field)))
```

But nothing, the value of field is "v0". How to make normal twothreaded example with cycles in each thread and with access to variable???

Comment: I be glad to all multithreaded samples in clojure!!!! In the end of my code, I added (deref (future (Thread/sleep 5000) (prn @field)) 0 (prn @field))

Comment: this helps to show "v1", but if evenI place (prn @field) before reset! in f1, I can't get "v2", this is the problem, I can't change @field from f2 to get it read in f1

Comment: try this chapter: http://www.braveclojure.com/concurrency/ it has some nice introduction to clojure's concurrency. And the whole book is quite nice too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch the docs of `deref`:

```
clojure.core/deref
([ref] [ref timeout-ms timeout-val])
```

returns the in-transaction-value of ref, else returns the
  most-recently-committed value of ref. When applied to a var, agent
  or atom, returns its current state. When applied to a delay, forces
  it if not already forced. When applied to a future, will block if
  computation not complete. When applied to a promise, will block
  until a value is delivered.  The variant taking a timeout can be
  used for blocking references (futures and promises), **and will return
  timeout-val if the timeout (in milliseconds) is reached before a
  value is available**. See also - realized?.

so your timeout is 0, that means it will return default value
which is `f2` - *a function value (not a function call)*, which is not being called obviously, so no `reset!` ever happens.

1. if you want "v1" you should deref like:

   `(deref (future (Thread/sleep 10) (f1)) 100 (f2))`
2. if you want "v2":

   `(deref (future (Thread/sleep 10) (f1)) 0 (f2))`